# Python project MQTT ConnectionError: Failed to receive Ack! (connection returned result: 5 non connack received)

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I was working on a project in python to run on a raspberry pi. I need to run an audio on different USB devices connected to my arduino.

I use node-red and mosquito server for the mqtt connection and I have a error during the connection to the server:
(I use pygame to play my audio tracks)

```
pygame 2.0.0.dev12 (SDL 2.0.9, python 3.7.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Connection returned result: 5
no connack received!
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3452, in _thread_main
    self.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1779, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1181, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1572, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2310, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2942, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_connack()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3030, in _handle_connack
    self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Lav_Fiverr_mqtt_player.py", line 32, in on_connect
    raise ConnectionError("Failed to receive Ack!")
ConnectionError: Failed to receive Ack!
```

Here is the code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys
from pygame import mixer
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, Queue
# ------------------------------------
channel_list = {}
# total_channels = mixer.get_num_channels()
playback_devices = 2

q = Queue(maxsize=100)
device_names = ["Speakers (USB PnP Sound Device)", "Speakers (2- USB PnP Sound Device)"]
# ------------------------------------------


# The callback when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection returned result: " + str(rc))
    if not rc:
        print('Connected to MQTT broker')

        client.subscribe("VOLUME/")

        client.subscribe("AUDIO/2/PLAY")
        client.subscribe("AUDIO/3/PLAY")
        client.subscribe("AUDIO/*/PLAY")

    else:
        # raise ConnectionError("Failed to get CONNACK!")
        print("no connack received!")
        raise ConnectionError("Failed to receive Ack!")
        # pass
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def play_music(payload):
    if "/" in payload and ".wav" in payload:
        lis_music_file = payload.split("/")
        channel_volume_info = lis_music_file[1].split("%")
        try:
            channel_volume = int(channel_volume_info[0].strip()) / 100
        except ValueError:
            print("Value Error on Channel Volume!. Setting Default Channel volume 100%")
            channel_volume = 1

        if os.path.isfile("wav_samples/" + str(lis_music_file[0])):
            print("File exists")
            curr_channel = mixer.find_channel()
            # channel_list[curr_channel] = lis_music_file[0]
            curr_channel.set_volume(channel_volume)
            curr_channel.play(mixer.Sound("wav_samples/" + str(lis_music_file[0])))

            print('playing now!')
            # curr_channel.set_volume(1)
            # print(channel_list)
        else:
            print("Playback file not found!")
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def playback(info) -> None:
    mixer.init(devicename=current_process().name)

    print("Process {} is running".format(current_process().name))
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if info.empty():
            pass
        else:
            msg = info.get(timeout=1)
            if msg is None:
                pass
            else:
                # topic = str(msg.topic)
                # payload = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
                topic, payload = msg.split(",")
                print('Data received on the subscribed topic {}'.format(topic))

                lis_topic_content = topic.split("/")
                topic_length = len(lis_topic_content)
                # volume_info  = lis_topic_content[topic_length-1].split("%")

            # --------------------- Playback on USB device 1---------------------------
                if current_process().name == "Speakers (USB PnP Sound Device)":
                    if topic_length == 3:
                        if lis_topic_content[2] == "PLAY" and lis_topic_content[1] == "2":
                            play_music(payload)

            # --------------------- Playback on USB device 2---------------------------
                        elif lis_topic_content[2] == "PLAY" and lis_topic_content[1] == "3":
                            info.put(msg)

            # --------------------- Playback on all USB devices---------------------------
                #         elif lis_topic_content[2] == "PLAY" and lis_topic_content[1] == "*":
                #             play_music(payload)

            # --------------------Volume Control--------------------------------
                    elif topic_length == 2:
                        if lis_topic_content[0] == "VOLUME":
                            lis_vol = payload.split("%")
                            try:
                                global_volume = int(lis_vol[0].strip())/100
                                mixer.music.set_volume(global_volume)
                                print("Volume is set to {}".format(global_volume))
                            except ValueError:
                                print("Value Error on Volume!")
            # -------------------------------------------------------------------

                elif current_process().name == "Speakers (2- USB PnP Sound Device)":
                    if topic_length == 3:
                        if lis_topic_content[2] == "PLAY" and lis_topic_content[1] == "2":
                            info.put(msg)
                        # --------------------- Playback on USB device 2---------------------------
                        elif lis_topic_content[2] == "PLAY" and lis_topic_content[1] == "3":
                            play_music(payload)
                        # --------------------- Playback on all USB devices---------------------------
                        # elif lis_topic_content[2] == "PLAY" and lis_topic_content[1] == "*":
                        #     play_music(payload)

                    # --------------------Volume Control--------------------------------
                    elif topic_length == 2:
                        if lis_topic_content[0] == "VOLUME":
                            lis_vol = payload.split("%")
                            try:
                                global_volume = int(lis_vol[0].strip()) / 100
                                mixer.music.set_volume(global_volume)
                                print("Volume is set to {}".format(global_volume))
                            except ValueError:
                                print("Value Error on Volume!")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# The callback when a PUBLISH message is received on susbsribed topic from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    print("Data {} is received on topic {}".format(str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8")), str(msg.topic)))
    # topic = str(msg.topic)
    # payload = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
# ------------------Main routine --------------------------
    # q.put(msg)
    q.put(str(msg.topic) + "," + str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    # process_request(topic, payload)
# --------------------------------------------------------------


def main():
    # proc_id = ["Proc"+str(i) for i in range(playback_devices)]
    proc_id = ["Speakers (USB PnP Sound Device)", "Speakers (2- USB PnP Sound Device)"]
    client = mqtt.Client("", True, None,  mqtt.MQTTv31)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    try:
        client.connect('mqtt.fluux.io', port=1883, keepalive=60)
        # client.connect('test.mosquitto.org', port=1883)
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        sys.exit(1)

    for i in range(len(proc_id)):
        Process(target=playback, name=proc_id[i], args=(q,)).start()

    time.sleep(1)
    # client.loop_forever()
    # client.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)
    client.loop_start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
# ------------------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please edit the code down to the [Minimal Viable Testcase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show the problem.

Comment: mqtt.fluux.io looks like it requires a username/password and/or TLS cert, and your code shows none of that.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the Paho [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#on-connect)

> 0. Connection successful
> 1. Connection refused - incorrect protocol version
> 2. Connection refused - invalid client identifier
> 3. Connection refused - server unavailable
> 4. Connection refused - bad username or password
> 5. Connection refused - not authorised
>
> 6-255: Currently unused.

When `rc` is 5 it means that user is not authorised to connect to the broker.

Comment: So how should I resolve this problem.
All the code works on a windows pc, but not on the raspberry pi

Comment: That is very unlikely unless you have changed something else (e.g. the host the broker is running on), as J D Allen said in the other comment, mqtt.flux.io looks like it requires authentication and you have not supplied any credentials in the code you have show